# R - How to benchmark an external logistic regression equation

Tags: r, logistic-regression

Suppose I have a logistic regression model from an outside group which I want to benchmark against a model I generated from dataset df. The external model has the equation Xo + 1.37X1 - 3.23X2 + 1.74X3. These variables exist in df and would be used to predict target variable Y.

My question is, how would I generate a new variable df$pred that is derived from this existing model?

To be clear, I don’t mean generating my own model using glm. This is strictly how I would test say, a previously published model as my performance benchmark. Thanks!

Comment: Seems related to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36173/understand-how-to-test-a-logit-model-on-new-data

Comment: This seems as simple as calculating the linear predictor, and passing to to the inverse link function to get your response vector. `with(data, binomial(link = "logit")$linkinv(X0 + 1.37 * X1 + 3.23 * X2 + 1.74 * X3))`. Similarly you'd then choose a threshold (say 50 %), where you'd accept the outcome as a 'succes' or 'failure'

Answer (score 0):

I think it's as simple as this, no?

```
# Create dummy dataset
X0 <- c(1,2,3)
X1 <- c(10,20,30)
X2 <- c(100,200,300)
X3 <- c(1000,2000,3000)
df <- data.frame(X0,X1,X2,X3)

# Calculate df$pred
df$pred <- X0 + 1.37*X1 - 3.23*X2 + 1.74*X3
```